# If my understanding of BCNF is correct, how did we know that R1 was not in BCNF?

Tags: database-design, normalization, relational-theory

> Given that `R(ABCDE)`
>
> `AB->C`
>
> `BC->D`
>
> `CD-> E`
>
> `DE->A`

Since, `B` is the only attribute absent on the right-hand side, we would start with `B`.

`{B}+ = B` . Not a CK.

Next, we combine different attribute with `B`.

`{AB}+ = AB = ABC = ABCD = ABCDE`. This is a CK.

`{BC}+ = BC = BCD = BCDE = BCDEA`. This is a CK.

`{BD}+ = BD` . Not a CK.

`{BE}+ = BE` . Not a CK.

`{BDE}+ = BDE = BDEA = BDEAC`. This is a CK.

So, total number of CK/minimal keys are 03 (three).

Since, in some FDs, attributes are not dependent on keys, `R` is not in BCNF.

---

(1) Finding the violating FDs:

`CD -> E` and `DE -> A` are the violations of BCNF. Coz, in these FDs, attributes are nor dependent on keys.

(3) Decomposition:

Start with any one of the invalid FDs:`CD -> E` .

(i) Find the closure of `CD` and decompose:

`R1 = {CD}+ = CD = CDE = CDEA = ACDE`

`R2 = (R - R1) + {CD} = (ABCDE - ACDE) + CD = BCD`

Now, we will have to check to see whether both R1 and R2 in BCNF.

> `R1(ACDE), R2(BCD)`
>
> `AB->C`
>
> `BC->D`
>
> `CD-> E`
>
> `DE->A`

**I have a question, how did we know that R1 was not in BCNF and needs to be decomposed?**

Since, `CD->E` is already applied in a decomposition, we don't need to use that again. Coz, it will produce the same result.

(1) Finding the violating FDs:

`DE->A` is violating the BCNF and it is also not applied yet.

(2) Decomposision:

Start with `DE->A`.

(i) Find the closure of DE and decompose:

`R3 = {DE}+ = DEA = ADE`.

`R4 = (R1 - R3) + {DE} = (ACDE - ADE) + {DE} = CDE`.

So, our final BCNF decompositions are,

```
R2{BCD}, 
R3{ADE},
R4{CDE}.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking:

> I have a question, how did we know that R1 was not in BCNF and needs to be decomposed?

In the BCNF Decomposition Algorithm, when a relation is decomposed, one should find the dependencies of the subschemas, in this case `R1(ACDE)` and `R2(BCD)`.

Let’s start from `R1`. To find the dependencies that hold in `R1`, one should actually project the original dependencies over the subschema, but, *for simplicity, we would consider only those dependencies in which all the attributes are present in the subschema.*

So, in `R1` the dependencies `{C D → E, D E → A}` hold, `C D` is the key, and the algorithm continues by searching if the dependency `D E → A` violates the BCNF (of course the first one does not violates it since `C D` is the key of `R1`).

And it is easy to see that `D E → A` violates the BCNF since `D E` is not a superkey of the relation, so that now `R1` must be decomposed.

So, the answer to your question is:

> The algorithm knows that R1 is not in BCNF simply by checking if the dependencies that hold in `R1` have a determinant which is not a superkey of `R1`.

---

**From comments:**

> After the 1st decomposition, we should calculate the minimal keys again. Am I correct?

We know the key of `R1` because of the way in which it is built (as the closure of the determinant of the original dependency `CD -> E`). We must find the key of `R2`, instead.

> Which part of my answer needs to be corrected?

Simply cancel the sentence *"Since, `CD->E` is already applied in a decomposition, we don't need to use that again. It will produce the same result."*, and continue with *"(1) Finding the violating FDs:
`DE->A` is violating the BCNF and it is also not applied yet..."*